# Merge nested objects without mutating

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I have the following 2 JavaScript Objects:

```
let o1 = {
  entities: {
    1: {
      text: "fooo",
      nested: {
        ids: [1, 2, 3],
        flag: true
      }
    }
  }
};

let o2 = {
  ids: [4, 5, 6]
}
```

I want to merge them without mutating them, to get an Object which looks like this:

```
let o3 = {
  entities: {
    1: {
      text: "fooo",
      nested: {
        ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        flag: true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

There could be n `entities`, but only the one defined by `entityId` should be affected.
What I tried:

```
let entityId = 1;

let o3 = Object.assign({}, o1, {
         entities: Object.assign({}, o1.entities, {
           [entityId]: Object.assign({}, o1.entities[entityId].nested,
            { ids: [...o1.entities[entityId].nested.ids, ...o2.ids] }
          )
        })
      });
```

The problem is that `text: "fooo",nested:` completely disappear.

Is my aproach right? Could this code be optimized?

Comment: *"to get an Object which looks like this:"* - You forgot to include the example output. Are you shooting for the same structure as `o1` but with the extra ids added to the array?

Comment: Sorry my fault, I changed it. Yes extactly

Comment: Your example input has an `entities` (plural) property, but with only the single `1` property. Could the real data have a `2`, `3`, etc., and if so which one should the ids from `o2` be merged with?

Comment: The example could have more `entities` and only the one set in variable `entityId` should be affected.

Comment: Merge `o1` into `o3` and then push items into `o3` array? Might be too simple for real use case though, but chaining `assign` like this is not readable at all, imho

Comment: Yes, also in my opinion this code is not readable at all... What do you mean exactly by "Merge o1 into o3 and then push items into o3 array"?

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged Redux, I will assume you are using React and suggest you use the immutability helper - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html

Your code would look like this:

```
let o3 = update(o1, {
    entities: {
        [entityId]: {
            nested: {
                ids: {
                    $push: [4, 5, 6]
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

---

**ES6**

Your logic is correct, but you are missing the `nested` object in your code:

```
let o3 = Object.assign({}, o1, {
     entities: Object.assign({}, o1.entities, {
       [entityId]: Object.assign({}, o1.entities[entityId], { 
          nested : Object.assign({}, o1.entities[entityId].nested ,{
            ids: [...o1.entities[entityId].nested.ids, ...o2.ids] }) 
        }
      )
    })
  });
```

Comment: I am using Angular2, I will check if there is a helper like this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Daskus There is probably nothing wrong with using Facebook's helper anyway, as it is a standalone module - https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: Oh you're right! But isn't using Immutable.js a problem when saving the state to localStorage?

Comment: @Daskus you would simply need to serialize/de-serialize before storing/retrieving.

Comment: I don't see how that would make any difference, as localStorage saves data as string

Comment: The difference is, as @steezeburger mentioned, that you need to serialize/de-serialize it

Comment: But wouldn't you have to serialize anyway, with mutable objects?

Comment: I think you are right...I will give Immutable.js a shot tomorrow and mabye I'll accept your answer ;)

Comment: Awesome ! It's worth its weight of peanuts

Answer (score 1):

If you know your data isn't going to include any dates or methods you could use the JSON deep-clone trick:

```
let o3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o1));
Array.prototype.push.apply(o3.entities[1].nested.ids, o2.ids);
```

Comment: In my real code I have dates as well so your aproach would not work...I tried to simplify the code.

Comment: It actually works with dates, but date objects (i.e. not timestrings, etc.) will be converted to an ISO string. To return them to a date object you can simply loop over `o3` (IMO a timestamp is usually better than a date object until you need it anyway). Unless you are working with huge datasets this method will be a lot more legible than attempting to write your own parser.

Comment: Alternatively look at lodash or jquery.clone

Answer (score 0):

Well, your first problem is this bit:

```
{
       [entityId]: Object.assign({}, o1.entities[entityId].nested,
```

where you're copying the value of `o1.entities[1].nested` into the key `o3.entities[1]` and thus losing the other keys from the object held in `o1.entities[1]`.

This is hard to see because, as the other comments have indicated, this isn't very pretty code.

You wanted to (and meant to) use `o1.entities[entityId]` instead, of course.

You have an additional problem, though, in that if you're only doing a *deep* copy on the part of `o1` that you're currently interested in. `Object.assign()` will copy object references, instead of creating entirely fresh objects. So if you later modify the value of `o3.entities[1].text`, you will also be mutating `o1.entities[1]`.

Comment: I don't think so, as I am passing a new, empty object as first param the object will be copied and not mutated: Object.assign({}, ...)

Comment: When an object is copied via `Object.assign()`, any values it contains that are themselves objects are merely copied by *reference*. So:

Comment: `let a = {foo: {}};`

`let b = Object.assign({}, a}; // Copies the contents of a into b`

`b.bar = {}; // a is unaffected since b is a discrete copy of a`

`b.foo.narf = 1; // a.foo is affected since it refers to the same object as b.foo`

`console.log(a.foo); // prints "{narf: 1}"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed one layer of merging - your example code has `entities.1.ids` instead of `entities.1.nested.ids`. Try

```
let entityId = 1;

let o3 = Object.assign(
  {},
  o1,
  {
    entities: Object.assign(
      {},
      o1.entities,
      {
        [entityId]: Object.assign(
          {},
          o1.entities[entityId],
          Object.assign(
            {},
            o1.entities[entityId].nested,
            { ids: [...o1.entities[entityId].nested.ids, ...o2.ids] }
          )
        )
      }
    )
  }
);
```

At this point, you probably want to build up some intermediate variables from each of the `Object.assign` calls just so you can keep track of everything a little better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do:

```
const merged = {
    entities: {
        [entityId]: {
            text: o1.entities[entityId].text,
            nested: {
                ids: [...o1.entities[entityId].nested.ids, ...o2.ids],
                flag: o1.entities[entityId].nested.flag
            }
        }
    }
}
```