# How can I make my React child components render even if a prop is missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, store, fluxible

TLDR; I need to be able to render child components in React even if a property of this.props is missing.

I have an React app built with [Yahoo's Flxubile](http://fluxible.io/). The app fetches data from a Wordpress site with WP REST API. Sometimes an image might be missing or something else from the API, this causes the client to break. Here's an example:

I have a file called Articles.js which is connected to ArticlesStore which holds my articles. I then render one Article.js for every article I have and pass props like this:

```
{   this.props.articles.map(function(el, index) {                                           
      return <Article key={index} article={el} />
    })
}
```

Everything is ok here, but then in my Article.js when I try to access properties that is not set I get the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sizes' of undefined

This is the line which causes the error:

```
<img src={this.props.article.meta_fields.image.sizes.large} />
```

This happens when a image is missing from an article. I understand the javascript error of course but I want to render the Article.js component event if a image url is missing from the API/Store. I have tried the following solutions, but it causes too much clutter and no control:

1. Conditional set if we have the prop i.e.
   {this.props.article.meta_fields.image ? this.props.article.meta_fields.image.sizes.large : "imagemissing.png"}
2. Setting defaultProps. This does not work because passed properties from parent to child overwrites defaultProps.

Maybe I should try something else than passing props from parent to child? Have a ArticleStore where I can set default values for every article? How would you do it?

Comment: Can't you just make a condition in render as to whether or not the prop is there, and return it without the image in case it isn't?

Comment: I had a same problem and solved it with giving default values, why does it give no control?

Comment: @cbll Then I have to make like 10 conditionals for every component I have. Would be really cluttered and I would have to spend a lot of time just to write conditionals.

Comment: @donquixote default values in the store or component? Because I can't use defaultProps because it gets overwritten in the child.

Comment: in component @SebastianMarcusson

Comment: For nested property merging with defaults, have a look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491840/merge-nested-objects-without-mutating

Comment: @donquixote Hmm, maybe. But the object is pretty big, so setting every nested property would be very time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide a nested structure as a prop (as with `article`) you'll want to be able to rely on the structure always being pretty much the same. In this case it won't be, sometimes the `meta_fields` does not have an `image`-attribute (as your TypeError suggests).

In your case I would consider pulling out the things you actually need/use in the `Article` component from the article object and pass those as props.

Say that your `Article` only uses `title`, `body`, and `image`. Then just pass those as props.

```
<Article title={ article.title } body={ article.body } image={ getImage(article) }/>

function getImage(article) {
    if (article.meta_fields.image
     && article.meta_fields.image.sizes
     && article.meta_fields.image.sizes.large
    ) {
        return article.meta_fields.image.sizes.large;
    }
    return 'default_image.jpg'; // Or whatever you want.
}
```

One might think that the extra props constitutes more "clutter" here, but given the choice between clutter and `TypeError`, I choose clutter.

And if you don't want to reinvent the wheel. The problem of accessing data in a nested structure like this have been solved before.

```
// Lodash
_.get(article, 'meta_fields.image.sizes.large', 'default_image.jpg')
// Ramda
_.pathOr('default_image.jpg', ['meta_fields', 'image', 'sizes', 'large'], article)
```

Comment: I went with the Lodash solution. It fit my needs the best.